# calling serviceAccount.json throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to implement a Google API in my project where I need to call the serviceAccount.json passing in the Credentials.

Here is my Code:

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIAL_FILE = "/home/and03/AndroidStudioProjects/Parent/app/src/main/res/assets/serviceAccount.json";


    private static final String OAUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement";
    AndroidManagement androidManagement;
    String json,abcd;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIAL_FILE);
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(input).createScoped(Collections.singleton(OAUTH_SCOPE));
            androidManagement = new AndroidManagement(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),credential);
            //createEnterprise(androidManagement);
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+ androidManagement );
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private String createEnterprise(AndroidManagement androidManagementClient)
            throws IOException {
        SignupUrl signupUrl =
                androidManagementClient
                        .signupUrls()
                        .create()
                        .setProjectId("managementtest")
                        .setCallbackUrl("https://unsplash.com/v1/signupUrls")
                        .execute();

        String enterpriseToken = displayUrlToAdmin(signupUrl.getUrl());

        Enterprise enterprise =
                androidManagementClient
                        .enterprises()
                        .create(new Enterprise())
                        .setProjectId("managementtest")
                        .setSignupUrlName(signupUrl.getName())
                        .setEnterpriseToken(enterpriseToken)
                        .execute();

        return enterprise.getName();
    }

    private String displayUrlToAdmin(String url) {
        Log.i("My Url",url);
       return url;
    }
}
```

This is a code I took from the Samples in the google's Documentation described here

[Android Management API:  create an enterprise](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise)

I know we need FileInputStream to call this file from assets folder but it  is still showing filenotfoundException.

there is another Sample App which show the full demonstration

Check out:

[Sample App for Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/sample-app)

I just want to know, how I can use the Path of the .json file in my app so that it will run correctly.

Comment: Did you fix the exception? If you did please let us know